# What is the best way to persist chatting data?

Tags: websocket, apache-kafka, chat, persist

I'm working on building a chat function in my android application.
I used WebSocket to communicate between clients and servers, and for the message broker I used Kafka. I'm planning to persist the chat message to storage but I'm not sure if it's appropriate to store the data in a RDBMS like MySQL.
Can anyone tell me where I should persist the data?

Answer (score 0):

If it is not going to scale heavily you can surely use RDBMS -Postgres for chat.  It will be better than MySQL because it is optimized for writing.

Ideally this is a go to case for Casandra which again is heavily optimized for writes.

For more details you can check out this link where Discord has given quite a lot of details about their usage for Casanadra.
https://blog.discord.com/how-discord-stores-billions-of-messages-7fa6ec7ee4c7